# Why cant I find the element of credit card number using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make an automated checkout system but I can't seem to send keys in fields of this payment box. Even when I try implicit wait and wait for it to load in it still doesn't work.

```
checkout = driver.find_element_by_id("number")
checkout.send_keys("9848432")
```

```html
<input required="" autocomplete="cc-number" id="number" name="number" type="tel" aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number" data-current-field="number" placeholder="Card number" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; padding: 0.94em 0.8em; transition: padding 0.2s ease-out 0s;">
```

[image: This is where I can't send keys in any field]

Here's [a link](https://kith.com/942252/checkouts/94758c4e91ae10f58b7ecbf8988f6484?_ctd=DZvDwstB1%2FhnAwhR7ALaALgvOTQyMjUyL2NoZWNrb3V0cy9jNjU0Y2E0MzIwMjlkNGFmNjU5ZTkxMzNhYTQ4ZGE2Mz9jb29raWVzX2Jsb2NrZWQ9MSZub19jb29raWVzX2Zyb21fcmVkaXJlY3Q9MSZwcmV2aW91c19zdGVwPXNoaXBwaW5nX21ldGhvZCZzdGVwPXBheW1lbnRfbWV0aG9kJnRva2VuPWI4ZjFiMDFmYWUyNWMxNmJiZDEzNmRiYmNmYTI0ZTkzy0HX%2BGcFmAAAy0HX%2BGcG2AAAAgDLQdf4ZwRkvGoB-290eRRPl8ysPwC%2Fe8PV8WKiHTTw%3D)!

Here is the URL you need to fill in the info until you get to the payment page, which is where I am having the issues

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! We would love to help you, but we don’t know what’s wrong with your code. please post minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Post it's html code as well.

Comment: @Dwade no buddy will write the html code for you by looking into an image when you can simply paste it as part of post itself.

Comment: better show real URL for this page. OR check if element is not in `<iframe>` because then it is treated as different page which you have to load using `switch_to.frame()`

Answer (score 1):

It might be in a nested iframe. A similar checkout due to not proper reproducible code.

```
<iframe src="https://fs.global-e.com/Checkout/v2/598d87e9-cd85-4f61-84df-81e345d62f05?gaSesID=526107767.603750114.583&amp;gaMerchantClientInfo=undefined@undefined&amp;chkcuid=b51f4449-13e2-4883-92ba-2641bb06ec51&amp;isNECAllowed=true&amp;vph=663&amp;ift=87" class="Intrnl_CO_Container" id="Intrnl_CO_Container" name="Intrnl_CO_Container" allowtransparency="true" width="100%" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" height="1000px" style="height: 3101px;">
    <iframe id="secureWindow" class="clear-fix clearfix" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%; min-height: 160px; height: 165px;" src="https://securev2.global-e.com/payments/CreditCardForm/598d87e9-cd85-4f61-84df-81e345d62f05/11">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-validation-error" data-type="unknown" data-type-id="1" data-val="true" data-val-luhn="Card number not valid" data-val-luhn-allowempty="False" data-val-luhn-allowspaces="False" data-val-required="Card number" id="cardNum" name="PaymentData.cardNum" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" placeholder="Card number" type="tel" value="">
    </iframe>
</iframe>
```

Which was solved with:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'Intrnl_CO_Container')))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'secureWindow')))
checkout = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cardNum")))
checkout.send_keys("9848432")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```